# Need .htaccess assistance

Tags: .htaccess

We have an existing site, let's call it ourdomain.com.  We moved content over from a site that is shutting down, let's call it legacydomain.com.  We pointed the legacy domain at our server to the /public_html/ folder.

What I need is an .htaccess that will redirect legacydomain.com or legacydomain/anything-here to ourdomain.com/legacydomain/ with nothing else appended to the URL.

However, I also need a few specific URLs to redirect to certain destinations, and they don't really follow a pattern.  For example:

legacydomain.com/something.html to ourdomain.com/legacydomain/something.html

legacydomain.com/another.html to ourdomain.com/legacydomain/folder/another.html

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.legacydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ourdomain.com/legacydomain/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /something.html http://www.ourdomain.com/legacydomain/another.html
```

It mostly works, but if I visit legacydomain.com/anything-here it doesn't even attempt to rewrite, it just keeps the domain the same and gives a 404.  And also I have a feeling that even if it did work, something like legacydomain.com/anything-here/more-stuff would get rewritten as ourdomain.com/legacydomain/anything-here/more-stuff which I don't want.

Only other thing in the .htaccess is rewriting non-www to www, and the standard WordPress stuff.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Everything above should have an http:// and www in front for the examples, but it wouldn't let me post that many "links".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each specific rewrite you would need two lines, as follows. Depending on your existing config you may need to add a slash at the beginning of the RewriteRule in front of something.html if this doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} legacydomain.com
RewriteRule something.html http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/something.html [R=301,L]
```

Then you would use a catch-all for everything else.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} legacydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me.  In your example, visiting legacydomain.com would redirect correctly, but legacydomain.com/something.html would not redirect and give me a 404 (tried with and without leading slash).  The catchall also didn't work as visiting legacydomain.com/anythingelse wouldn't get rewritten either.  Really weird, it's like once I add a slash to the URL in the browser RewriteCond just won't match anything no matter what, but what you have looks right.  Any reason that might happen?  I wonder if it is a WordPress thing.

Comment: Ok, so I moved your suggestions above the WordPress rules and everything is working perfectly!!  I can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go for the simplest solution which doesn't use mod_rewrite. First, just redirect the specific pages to wherever they need to go.

```
Redirect 301 /something.html http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/something.html
Redirect 301 /another.html http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/another.html
```

Then, simply redirect everything else to the base URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*) http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/
```

These must be put in your .htaccess file before the `RewriteEngine on` statement.

Comment: The only issue with that is two domains are pointing to the same directory and loading the same .htaccess file.  So your RedirectMatch line would also match http://ourdomain.com/anything and try to rewrite it as http://ourdomain.com/legacydomain/ .  Any suggestions on what to do about that?  Maybe when I create legacydomain.com as an addon domain in cPanel I should give it its own directory so it can have its own .htaccess rather than pointing it at public_html?  Thanks.